# How to center the first row?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multirow

[image]

```
\begin{table*}
\caption{Table Name}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllllll} 
    \toprule[.1em]
\multirow{Ref} &\multicolumn{6}{l}{User Profile Based Features} & \multicolumn{10}{l}{Content Based Features} \\ 
\midrule[.1em]
 & DF & FFC & TSF & LF & UPF & GF & BoW & TF-IDF & TF & CF & WPF & SNF & PF & Fsem & Fsen & VF \\ 
 \midrule[.1em]
2 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
3 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & \checkmark & ~ \\ 
\hline
4 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
5 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark \\ 
\hline
6 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & \checkmark & \checkmark & ~ \\ 
\hline
7 & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
8 & \checkmark & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
10 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & \checkmark & ~ \\ 
\hline
11 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
12 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
13 & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
16 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
18 & \checkmark & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
22 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ \\ 
\hline
25 & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
26 & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ \\ 
\hline
28 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Your LaTeX code is unreadable, please use the formatting tools provided by this site. It's also incomplete, since I don't see any `\documentclass` or `\begin(document}`. Finally, it'd easier if you wrote a proper explanation of what you want and what the problem is. Thank you.

Comment: `\multirow{Ref}` is just wrong syntax. It should have given a LaTeX error.

Comment: How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you would want to put `Ref` vertically centered on the first two rows, you would also eliminate the horizontal line in the first column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\caption{Table Name}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllllll} 
    \toprule[.1em]
\multirow{2}{*}[-0.5ex]{Ref} &\multicolumn{6}{l}{User Profile Based Features} & \multicolumn{10}{l}{Content Based Features} \\ 
\cmidrule[.1em]{2-17}
 & DF & FFC & TSF & LF & UPF & GF & BoW & TF-IDF & TF & CF & WPF & SNF & PF & Fsem & Fsen & VF \\ 
 \midrule[.1em]
2 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
3 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & \checkmark & ~ \\ 
\hline
4 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
5 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark \\ 
\hline
6 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & \checkmark & \checkmark & ~ \\ 
\hline
7 & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
8 & \checkmark & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
10 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & \checkmark & ~ \\ 
\hline
11 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
12 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
13 & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
16 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
18 & \checkmark & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
22 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ \\ 
\hline
25 & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
\hline
26 & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ \\ 
\hline
28 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & \checkmark & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful and I actually wanted First row "User Profile Based Features" and "User Profile Based Features" to appear in the center.

Comment: Use `\multicolumn{…}{c}`

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are looking for this:

```
\multirow{2}{*}{Ref}
```

for your first two rows of the 1st column